# How do I capture a "response end" event in node.js+express?

Tags: events, node.js, express, response

I'd like to write an express middleware function that sets up a listener on the response's 'end' event, if one exists.  The purpose is to do cleanup based on the http response code that the end handler decided to send, e.g. logging the response code and rollback/commit of a db transaction.  i.e., I want this cleanup to be transparent to the end caller.

I'd like to do something like the following in express:

The route middleware

```
function (req, res, next) {
   res.on ('end', function () {
      // log the response code and handle db
      if (res.statusCode < 400) { db.commit() } else { db.rollback() }
   });
   next();
}
```

The route:

```
app.post ("/something", function (req, res) { 
    db.doSomething (function () {
       if (some problem) {
          res.send (500);
       } else {
          res.send (200);
       }
    });
 }
```

When I try this, the 'end' event handler never gets called.  The same for `res.on('close')`, which I read about in another post.  Do such events get fired?

The only other way I can think of doing this is wrapping `res.end` or `res.send` with my own version in a custom middleware.  This is not ideal, because `res.end` and `res.send` don't take callbacks, so I can't just wrap them, call the original and then do my thing based on the response code that got set when they call me back (because they won't call me back).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you do the housekeeping stuff before `res.end`?

Comment: That's fine too, but I want to do it as middleware, i.e. without the end handler having to worry about the cleanup.  So if I want to log the resulting response code, or rollback/commit the db transaction based on the response code, I want that to operate transparently to the end handler.  So I'm trying to trap execution at some point between the end handler calling res.send and the request being done.

Comment: But **you** are defining the status code :/

Comment: I am?  I'm writing a route middleware function.  The end handler defines the return code.  I want to do things in response to what they decided to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.send%28%29), here is the signature of `res.send`:

```
res.send(body|status[, headers|status[, status]])
```

Which means you can set your own status, like this: `res.send( 'some string', 200 );` or even just `res.send( 404 );`.

This method is the one you use to *send* the response.

Once it is sent to the client, you can't access it anymore, so there is no callback.

**This is the last thing your server does. Once it has processed the request, it sends the response.**

However, you can access it *before* you send it to the client. Which means you can:

```
console.log( res );
res.send( datas );
```

If you want to rollback/commit, you do it when the database's callback is called, not when the response is gone.

Comment: Thanks.  From your answer, it sounds like the way I'd like to do things is simply impossible without replacing res.send with my own version that does the cleanup then calls the real res.send.

Comment: Yes, `res.send()` is the last thing your app will do when processing the request, so if you want any cleanup you have to do it before :)

Comment: res.on ('header',func) FTW!

Comment: The answer is incorrect. See answers below for using res.on('finish',...) to attach an event handler to fire when the response is sent.

Answer (score 50):

Strangely enough, it appears that the response emits a "finish" event when the response is closed:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120825112648/http://sambro.is-super-awesome.com/2011/06/27/listening-for-end-of-response-with-nodeexpress-js/

Despite this blog entry being a bit old, this event still exists ([Line 836 in lib/http.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L836)), so I assume it won't disappear soon, even though neither node's nor express' documentation mention it.
By early 2014 it has moved to [line 504 on of lib/_http_outgoing.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L504) and still works.

By the way, the "error" event on a server response is probably not something you'd usually want to see.

Comment: +1 I couldn't find the documentation, but the current source code (as of today) still raises the event.  Thanks!

Comment: Cant make it work with finish or end or close. any suggestions?

Comment: res.on ('header',func) FTW!

Comment: Is this the documented 'finish' event ? : http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish

Comment: Express.js response extends built-in http response, and finish event is not express-specific, therefore it's not in express docs

Answer (score 44):

Just to further @Amatsuyu's response, here's how it should look:

```
res.on('finish', function() {
  // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to get access to the final state of res within the callback? For example, could the callback look into res and pull out data that was sent to the client?

Comment: Yes @MatthewHerbst. Since this event listener is being handled inside the app.use call, just use the same "res" object from there.

Comment: I believe the `finish` event is not emitted if the client closes the connection before the response was sent. In this case only the `close` event is emitted.