# Log response status in sails

Tags: node.js, logging, sails.js

I'm trying to log every request made to my sails application, but I can't find a way to log the response associated with a request.

I added this custom middleware in the config/http.js file :

```
myRequestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
  req.on("end", function(){
    sails.log(res.statusCode);
  });
  return next();
}
```

But it doesn't work properly, I can get the 200 codes, buta res.forbidden or res.notFound response is not logged. Any idea about how I could handle that ?

Thank you

Comment: I used your exact example and was able to log 403 and 404 errors.  Please show your entire config/http.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the answer by reading this stackoverflow post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11841877/2700309

Apparently there is a 'finish' event emitted just before the response is send to the client. So the right code would be :

```
myRequestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
  res.on("finish", function(){
  sails.log(res.statusCode);
 });
 return next();
}
```

And this seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

You can override that in `api/responses` itself. Here is simplified override:

```
// api/responses/forbidden.js
module.exports = function(err, viewOrRedirect) {
  // ... Sails logic
  this.req._sails.log.verbose();
}
```

But, if you expect that your middleware above can do this, you're wrong. Your middleware should looks similar to this:

```
myRequestLogger: function(req, res, next) {
  req._sails.log.verbose('YOUR LOG');
  return next();
}
```

Comment: My problem is no to log something but to log the response object before it is send to the client... I although did a typo in my code above so I will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Then try to override responses in `api/responses` as I described above.